# Алгоритм перебора комбинаций из 2-ух элементов

Tags: алгоритм

**ЭТО НЕ ОБЫЧНЫЕ СОЧЕТАНИЯ!** Нужен алгоритм, который генерирует значения возможных комбинаций из 2-ух элементов (буду рад любому количеству), которые используются строго определенное количество раз - ни больше ни меньше. Грубо говоря, алгоритм размещает определенное количество заданого элемента всеми возможными вариантами. Для примера даю вызов функции и результат работы в массиве:

```
combination(8,4){   //8 - длина строки для размещения 4 элементов
  //код
}
```

---

результат в массив:

```
array[]={
00001111,
00010111,
00011011,
00011101,
...,
11110000}
```

Для лучшего понимания, даю ссылку на онлайн-рассчитанные варианты - http://integraloff.net/TepBep/cnk.php , введите там значение 8 и 4.

Comment: а чем вас лобовая рекурсия не устраивает? Какие ограничения на N и K?

Comment: перебор ВСЕХ возможных комбинаций не устраивает, т.к. в данном варианте нужно чтобы в каждой строке было четыре 0 и четыре 1

Comment: я понял что вы хотите сделать. Что именно у вас не получилось? Или слишком долго работает?

Comment: я пробовал разные варианты. Верного не смог ни написать, ни найти в интернете. Конечно, я знаю брут-способ - перебрать ВСЕ варианты и из них ифами извлечь нужные строки :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простейший вариант на C++ (от языка тут ничего не зависит почти). Идея почти такая же что и в генерации следующей перестановки элементов.

```
bool next_combination (vector<int> & a) {
    int C1 = 0;
    for (int i = a.size() - 1; i>=0; i--)
        if (a[i]) C1++;
        else if (C1){
            a[i] = 1;
            for (int j=a.size() -1; j > i; j--)
                a[j] = (--C1 > 0);
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> P = {0,0,0,1,1};
    do {
        for (auto x: P)
            cout << x<< " ";
        cout << endl;
        cin.get();
    } while (next_combination(P));
}
```

Comment: Насколько вектор на С++ заменяем массивом на Яве?

Comment: @АрсенКул тут полностью. Используется только его размер.

Comment: хм, на С++ return может возвращать несколько раз результат всего за один вызов? И, насколько я понял, true=1, false=0? Кажется на Яве так просто это не реализовать... ведь возврат только 1 на вызов.

Comment: Кхм... тут тоже 1 возврат за вызов. 1/0 true/false это как вам удобнее

Comment: Заменил все тру/фолсы на 1/0. Несмотря на полное внешнее сходство, алгоритм не доходит до внутреннего цикла, а впадает в бесконечный залуп. Может я как-то неправильно сконвертировал код? Перепишите, пожалуйста, код:
 if (a[i]) C1++;
        else if (C1){
            a[i] = 1;
            for (int j=a.size() -1; j > i; j--)
                a[j] = (--C1 > 0);
            return true;
        }
    return false;

так, чтобы были цифры а не boolean

Comment: @АрсенКул я не совсем вас понимаю, в примере цифры а не булевские значения.

Comment: выражение if(a[i]) Ява не понимает, ей нужно if(a[i]==1). И так далее

Comment: @АрсенКул там везде в таких неявных сравнениях не равно 0 (!=0) писать надо.

Comment: Не могу перевести на Яву. Есть несколько несостыковок. Вот мой код:
http://pastebin.com/2bwHaEDN. Некоторые неясные моменты записаны в коментах. Посмотрите, правильно ли сделал перевод некоторых строк? А то что-то гложут сомнения на счет преобразования типов и правильного порядка выполнения операторов в С++

Comment: не так. Буду за компом попроавлю. Из проблем - то что возвращает функция - это именно булевой значение,  показывающее остались ещё комбинации или нет. Ну и следующая комбинация сразу генерируется в массиве, именно массив и надо распечатывать в строку.

Answer (score 1):

Задача несложно решается рекурсией. Например, так.

Заметим, что все сочетания из n по k получаются так: это сочетания из (n - 1) по k с приписанным в конце нулём, плюс сочетания из (n - 1) по (k - 1) с приписанной в конце единицей.

Отсюда код (C#):

```
IEnumerable<List<int>> Combinations(int n, int k)
{
    if (k < 0 || k > n) yield break;
    if (n <= 0) { yield return new List<int>(); yield break; }

    foreach (var res in Combinations(n - 1, k))
    {
        res.Add(0);
        yield return res;
    }
    foreach (var res in Combinations(n - 1, k - 1))
    {
        res.Add(1);
        yield return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: результат бы кешировать, а то сложность слишком страшная выходит...

Comment: посмотрите на мой ответ, спиной чувствую что его можно ускорить до O(1) на 1 сочетание...

Comment: почему нету? грубо говоря отрезаем [01][10] и одно и тоже перевычисляем дальше (n-2,k-1)

Comment: @pavel: Ну, общее количество операций 2 * C_n^k (доказывается рекурсивно), так что особо больших потерь вроде нет?

Comment: К несчастью, С# не знаю. Мне нужно как-то переписать на Яву, но что тут за yield я не знаю. И я использую не список, а простой массив. Вроде на Яве Integer можно перебирать форичем, но неважно, для меня это уже мелочи жизни.

Comment: @АрсенКул: Ну, на Яве у вас не выйдет yield. Yield производит один элемент результата, так что у вас это будет просто запись в ArrayList, наверное.

Comment: @VladD у меня компилятора нет под рукой, проверьте на тесте [n = 100, k =2] у меня получилась дикое количество операций вашего алгоритма, у меня всё шустро отработало...

Comment: @pavel: Хм, если это так, то мой код выходит O(n) в среднем на элемент? (Ваш по сути тоже, т. к. перебор по вектору длины `n`).

Comment: @pavel: Сейчас перепроверю, момент.

Comment: @VladD `if (n <= 0) yield break;` -> `if (n <= 0) { yield new List<int>(); yield break; }`? Кто-то ведь должен создавать `List<int>`, которые Вы возвращаете.

Comment: @pavel: У меня для n = 100, k = 2 вышло всего 333499 вызовов `Combinations`, C_100^2 = 4950, да, слишком много.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Ага, как раз исправил.

Comment: @pavel: Хотя нет, у меня порядка 100 вызовов на элемент, то есть по идее не так уж и плохо.