# Рекурсивная генерация двоичных последовательностей с заданным количеством единиц

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, псевдокод

Даны числа `n` и `k`, где:

`n` - длина битовой последовательности

`k` - количество единиц в этой последовательности

Необходимо написать функцию, которая будет выводить все последовательности с ровно `k` единицами в лексикографическом порядке, используя рекурсию.

Функция `binary(k, n)` имеет только два параметра - `k` и `n`.

Думал, что надо вывести `binary(k - 1, n - 1) + '1'` и `binary(k, n - 1) + '0'`, рассматривая случаи `n == k`, `k == 0` и так далее, но не получилось...

Comment: Необходимо написать функцию- на чем написать?

Comment: Мне нужно на C++, но псевдокода тоже хватит

Comment: Ну раз у тебя никаких ограничений на время/память и нет требований про оптимальности - пиши просто рекурсивно получение всех последовательностей длины N. А выводи только те, в которых K единиц...

Comment: 1 секунда / 64 мегабайта

Comment: Олимпиады нужно решать самостоятельно. Стыдитесь.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Print all permutation in lexicographic order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29928236/4279)

Comment: @VladD это не олимпиада, я для себя решаю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вариант придумался...

```
void binary(int n, int k)
{
    static string prefix;
    if (n < k) return;
    if (n == 0) { cout << prefix << endl; return; }
    prefix.push_back('0');
    binary(n-1,k);
    prefix.pop_back();
    if (k >= 1)
    {
        prefix.push_back('1');
        binary(n-1,k-1);
        prefix.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, все работает!

Comment: ох спорили мы один раз на эту тему)  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567314/Алгоритм-перебора-комбинаций-из-2-ух-элементов кстати, а не дубль ли это?

Comment: @pavel Со мной?...

Comment: @Harry с владом). Я просто кинул ссылку, вот не нравится мне рекурсивный алгоритм для этой задачи есть честно.

Answer (score 1):

Прямолинейный алгоритм:

- если количество единиц равно нулю, то вернуть одни нули
- если длина последовательности равна количеству единиц, то вернуть одни единицы
- зная все возможные последовательности `n-1` битов c `k` единицами, можно получить в правильном лексикографическом порядке последовательность с `n` битами приставив `0` слева
- зная все возможные последовательности `n-1` битов c `k-1` единицами, можно получить последовательность с `n` битами и `k` единицами приставив `1` слева  (все варианты с нулём слева уже исчерпаны в предыдущем пункте)

На Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
def binary(n, k):
    if k == 0:  # no bits set
        yield '0' * n
    elif n == k:  # all bits set
        yield '1' * k
    else:
        assert n > k > 0
        for bits in binary(n - 1, k):
            yield '0' + bits
        for bits in binary(n - 1, k - 1):
            yield '1' + bits
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/fZWF5R):

```py
for bits in binary(4, 3):
    print(*bits)
```

Результат:

```
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

Трансляция на С++:

```
using Bits = std::string;    

void binary(int n, int k, std::function<void(Bits)> yield) {
  if (k == 0) // no bits set
    yield(Bits(n, '0'));
  else if (n == k) // all bits set
    yield(Bits(k, '1'));
  else {
    assert(n > k && k > 0);
    binary(n - 1, k,     [&yield](Bits bits) { yield("0" + bits); });
    binary(n - 1, k - 1, [&yield](Bits bits) { yield("1" + bits); });
  }
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/Ay9yoa):

```
int main() {
  int n, k;
  if(!(std::cin >> n >> k && n >= k && k >= 0))
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  binary(n, k, [](Bits bits) { std::cout << bits << '\n'; });
}
```